# NSURLConnection deprecated in iOS9

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, ios9

I want to download a file with a `NSURLRequest` and save it but in the line with the

`NSData * data = ...` happens an error.

```
NSURL *Urlstring = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourdomain.com/yourfile.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: Urlstring];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
documentsURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"localFile.pdf"];

[data writeToURL:documentsURL atomically:YES];
```

The warning Message is that i should use `NSURLSession dataTaskwithrequest`"because `sendSynchronousRequest` is deprecated in iOS 9 but that doesn't work I hope someone can help me

Comment: "Deprecated" isn't an error.  It's a warning that something is going away in the future.  If you have an actual error, it's probably for a different reason.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Now you have to use `NSURLSession`

**Example (GET):**

```
-(void)placeGetRequest:(NSString *)action withHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))ourBlock {

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", URL_API, action];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:ourBlock] resume];
}
```

Now you will need to call that method with an action (or your full URL if you prefer) and the block that will be executed when the API call return.

```
[self placeGetRequest:@"action" withHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // your code
}];
```

Inside that block, you will received a `NSData` with the response data and `NSURLResponse` with the HTTP response. So now, you can put your code there:

```
NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
documentsURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"localFile.pdf"];

[data writeToURL:documentsURL atomically:YES];
```

**Main difference between NSURLSession and NSURLConnection**

- NSURLConnection: if we have an open connection with NSURLConnection and the system interrupt our App, when our App goes to background mode, everything we have received or sent were lost.
  [image: Process diagram for NSURLConnection]
- NSURLSession: solve this problem and also give us out of process downloads. It manage the connection process even when we don't have access. You will need to use `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler` in your AppDelegate 
  [image: Process diagram for NSURLSession]

> So with the use of NSURLSession, you don't need to manage or to check
>   your internet connection because OS does it for you.

Comment: Ok Thank you but what is ourBlock it says undeclared identifier

Comment: Oh yes! ourBlock is a block that you have to define. It should include the source code that you want to execute when the api call finished. I will edit my answer to give you the full example

Comment: @Maximilian, check now my updated answer and test it inside your project

Comment: @EnriMR, looks like `dataTaskWithRequest` lacks `resume`, no?
`[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:ourBlock] resume];`

Comment: Yes, resume is missing. It seems the execution never goes to ourBlock without it.

Comment: Yes, I forgot it, I have realised that @diidu had fix it ;)