# swift posting to php using http request

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection

trying to send variables entered in text fields to a php script to write into an sql database.  attempting to use HTTP request

```
@IBAction func submit(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let requestURL = NSURL(string: "***************")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let song=txt1.text!
    let artist=txt2.text!
    let album=txt3.text!
    let year=txt4.text!
    let genre=txt5.text!


    let songPost = "song=" + (song as String)
    let artistPost = "&artist=" + (artist as String)
    let albumPost = "&album=" + (album as String)
    let yearPost = "&year=" + (year as String)
    let genrePost = "&genre=" +  (genre as String)

    request.httpBody = songPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    request.httpBody = artistPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    request.httpBody = albumPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    request.httpBody = yearPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    request.httpBody = genrePost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.mainQueue)
```

I get an error on the bottom line of code reading: Missing argument for parameter 'completion hander' in call.

not sure what this means.

Comment: Don't use `NSURLConnection`. It's deprecated in iOS 9. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441229/nsurlconnection-deprecated-in-ios9

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually extremely clear here. This method has a third parameter called `completionHandler` which you are missing. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlconnection/1418125-sendasynchronousrequest). Replace your last line with this:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.mainQueue)
{
  response, data, error in
  // handle response here
}
```

Comment: You changed the question completely. I undid your change. If you have a new question you should post it separately.

Comment: I did post a new question sorry I'm new to this site!! i figured since it was similar in nature i could just edit it but I went ahead and posted a new one, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, you should not use `NSURLConnection` anymore. But I answer your question, because it might help you, if you get a similar error in the future.

---

The message says, that you are calling a function with less parameters than required. In this case, the `completionHandler` is missing.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.mainQueue, completionHandler: {
     response , data, error in
})
```

In Swift 3, you can make a completion handler like this, too:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.main) {
    response , data, error in
    // your code here
}
```

---

BTW: In Swift, you don't need to use `NSMutableURLRequest`. `URLRequest` is already mutable by using `var`.

Comment: What is go in //your code here? I haven't used this method before I stumbled across it on the internet but Xcode kept throwing errors at me, I'm new to xcode

Comment: @xteetsx there you can put the code that you want to execute, after the request finished. The HTTP-Request runs asynchronously (in the background). That means, that the line after `sendAsynchronousRequest()` will immediately be executed, but the code within the `completionHandler()` waits for the request to finish

Comment: NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request), queue:**This was corrected to ';' now it says 'expected expression'*** OperationQueue.main) {
    response , data, error in
    // your code here
}

Comment: are you using Swift 3? Or still 2.x?

Comment: I've been using swift 3

Comment: oh. I just saw a typo in my code :-D Remove the ) after `request`

Comment: It says its expecting an expression where i put the ***'s is there a way to do this in swift 3?

Comment: Assuming that `request` is of type `URLRequest`, the second codepiece compiles without errors using Swift 3